# .htaccess complex and tricky redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am not expert in .htaccess that my need bit complex and tricky help..!

Here is my current `.htaccess` and remember i need some `.htaccess` that can destroy my current `.htaccess`.

Current `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^join$  https://example.com/internalpath/join/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^join/(.*)$ https://example.com/internalpath/join/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now my problem:

I want to redirect each and every file and directories to HTTP, except these two:

> https://example.com/join/
>
> https://example.com/join

Remember, I want every link on http except this above provided link, other then all files and directories and even files and directories in /join/ or /join will be HTTP, just two links on HTTP, but please it will not destroy the previous written .htaccess.

Comment: What is the destination URL/Path?

Comment: Except for /join and /join/ redirect all links to where?

Comment: to HTTP protocol , not a single link to be redirected on HTTPS except these two, /join and /join/

Answer (score 0):

Try this (not tested):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/join/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/internalpath/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: It is redirecting the page
https://domain.com/join/terms.php
to http://domain.com/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/skengine/join/join/terms.php

Comment: But when i type in browser https://domain.com its redirecting to https i want it to http , except "join" directory, but files and folders in "join"directory also must be redirected to http

Comment: are you still there for help please?

Answer (score 0):

You need these 3 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(join/.+)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/internalpath/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(join)/?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/internalpath/$1/index.php [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^join http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]
```