# .htaccess complex and very tricky redirection

Tags: .htaccess

Here is my current .htaccess and remember I need some .htaccess that can destroy my current .htaccess.

Current .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^join$  https://example.com/internalpath/join/index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^join/(.*)$ https://example.com/internalpath/join/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Now my problem:

I want to redirect each and every file and directories to HTTP, except these two:

```
https://example.com/join/

https://example.com/join
```

Remember, I want every link on http except this above provided link, other then all files and directories and even files and directories in /join/ or /join will be HTTP, just two links on HTTP, but please it will not destroy the previous written .htaccess.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of a question you already posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444015/htacess-complex-and-tricky-redirection

Answer (score 0):

Above thr rules that you have add this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !^join/?$ http://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```